# Filter by newly created column not working

Tags: sql, filter

In our database, there are multiple rows for the same `Request_number` (one row per request status, each row has its own `Request_ID`). However for each `Request_ID`, the `User_ID` is only showing in one of the rows and therefore, I created a new column using the `FIRST_VALUE` function so that I could fill the NULLs with the User_ID. I called the new column `Participant`. When I try to filter the requests using this newly created column, it is showing an error message.

Here is the query that I wrote :

```
WITH Grp as
(SELECT req.[Request_ID]
      ,[Request_number]
      ,[User_ID]
  FROM [Data2].[Counter].[Requests_Facts] req
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [Data2].[Counter].[Contributor] cont on req.Request_ID = cont.Request_ID)

  SELECT req.[Request_ID]
      ,[Request_number]
      ,typ.[Description] as 'Request subject'
      ,req.[Date_Created]
      ,req.[Date_Started]   
      ,req.[End_Date]   
      ,req.[Date_Modified]  
      ,[Date_Processed]
      ,loc.[Description] as 'Location'
      ,team.[Description] as 'Team' 
      ,ori.[Description] as 'Origin'    
      ,pri.[Description] as 'Priority'  
      ,comp.[Description] as 'Complexity'   
      ,sts.[Description] as 'Status'    
      ,req.[Language]
      ,sec.[Description] as 'Sector'
      ,FIRST_VALUE(User_ID) OVER(Partition by Request_number, Request_number ORDER BY User_ID DESC) as 'Participant'
      FROM [Data2].[Counter].[Requests_Facts] req
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [Counter].[Contributor] cont on req.Request_ID = cont.Request_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [Counter].[RequestType] typ on req.ID_RequestType = typ.ID_RequestType    
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [Counter].[Location] loc on req.ID_Location = loc.ID_Location 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [Counter].[Team] team on req.ID_Team = team.ID_Team   
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [Counter].[Origin] ori on req.ID_Origin = ori.ID_Origin   
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [Counter].[Priority] pri on req.ID_Priority = pri.ID_Priority 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [Counter].[Complexity] comp on req.ID_Complexity = comp.ID_Complexity 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [Counter].[Statuts] sts on req.ID_Status = sts.ID_Status  
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [Counter].[Sector] sec on req.ID_Sector = sec.ID_Sector
  WHERE [Participant] = '1234'
```

I'm getting this error message:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 36
> Invalid column name 'Participant'

I tried changing this

```
WHERE [Participant] = '1234'
```

to this

```
WHERE FIRST_VALUE(User_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY Request_number, Request_number ORDER BY User_ID DESC) = '1234'
```

But now I'm getting this error:

> Msg 4108, Level 15, State 1, Line 36
> Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses

I am just a beginner and I would appreciate some help. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to make another CTe as the the window function are genrated after the query has run.

```
WITH Grp as
(SELECT req.[Request_ID]
      ,[Request_number]
      ,[User_ID]
  FROM [Data2].[Counter].[Requests_Facts] req
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [Data2].[Counter].[Contributor] cont on req.Request_ID = cont.Request_ID), cteparticipant as

(  SELECT req.[Request_ID]
      ,[Request_number]
      ,typ.[Description] as 'Request subject'
      ,req.[Date_Created]
      ,req.[Date_Started]   
      ,req.[End_Date]   
      ,req.[Date_Modified]  
      ,[Date_Processed]
      ,loc.[Description] as 'Location'
      ,team.[Description] as 'Team' 
      ,ori.[Description] as 'Origin'    
      ,pri.[Description] as 'Priority'  
      ,comp.[Description] as 'Complexity'   
      ,sts.[Description] as 'Status'    
      ,req.[Language]
      ,sec.[Description] as 'Sector'
      ,FIRST_VALUE(User_ID) OVER(Partition by Request_number, Request_number ORDER BY User_ID DESC) as 'Participant'
      FROM [Data2].[Counter].[Requests_Facts] req
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [Counter].[Contributor] cont on req.Request_ID = cont.Request_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [Counter].[RequestType] typ on req.ID_RequestType = typ.ID_RequestType    
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [Counter].[Location] loc on req.ID_Location = loc.ID_Location 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [Counter].[Team] team on req.ID_Team = equ.ID_Team    
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [Counter].[Origin] ori on req.ID_Origin = ori.ID_Origin   
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [Counter].[Priority] pri on req.ID_Priority = pri.ID_Priority 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [Counter].[Complexity] comp on req.ID_Complexity = comp.ID_Complexity 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [Counter].[Statuts] sts on req.ID_Status = sts.ID_Status  
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [Counter].[Sector] sec on req.ID_Sector = sec.ID_Sector)
SELECT *  FROM cteparticipant 
  WHERE [Participant] = '1234'
```